# In what contexts do I use the collocation "get home" and "get back home"?

Tags: collocations

Could you tell me in what contexts I use *get home* and *get back home*. For example, which one I use in the following context?

> I am going out to meet up with some friends.I will **get home**/**get back home** in an hour.

Are there situations where I would use *get home* but not *get back home* and the other way around?

Comment: You might use _get back home_ if you were speaking to someone that you live with - seeing your absence from home from their point of view - or in relation to the length of time the house had been empty. But there are no rules about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In British English we tend to say "get *back* home" to indicate that we are *returning*, or returning for a specific reason. We might also just say "get back".

To be honest though, in the context of your example where you are still at home when you say it (you are announcing that you are going out), it would be more natural to say:

> I am going out to meet up with some friends.I will **be home** in an hour.

or

> I am going out to meet up with some friends.I will **be back** in an hour.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Let's say I went out for groceries I am already back. Do I say I "I just got home" or "I just got back home"?

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope Honestly, either. "Back" suggests you made a round trip, ie you went out and then came back.

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope Hi. If this answer (or any in general) helps you solve your problem, you should upvote them. This rewards the answerer a bit. You don't need to do this, but it is generally a good thing to do. :)